# Can BlockingQueue make MemorySegment visible for multiple threads?

Tags: java, visibility, project-panama

I am using JDK20's FFI, and I need to pass a Object to a BlockingQueue to shared it from one thread to another. The Object contains several MemorySegment field, which belongs to `Arena.openShared()`. Before passing, I write some bytes into the MemorySegment using `MemorySegment.set(JAVA_BYTE, ..., ...)`. I don't know if the other thread would read exactly what I write, since I am not using `VarHandle.setVolatile()` to ensure its thread visibility. But as Java Objects, there should be locks in BlockingQueue to ensure it, I wonder if it's also appliable to the `MemorySegment`, that each byte would be flushed to the memory for other threads to see them.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Specification for `BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), you can find the following paragraph:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a `BlockingQueue` [*happen-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the `BlockingQueue` in another thread.

As `BlockingQueue` establishes a happen-before relationship, no additional synchronization is needed.

Comment: Note that there’s an [API Note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/package-summary.html#:~:text=of%20this%20API.-,API%20Note,-%3A) saying “*Usual memory model guarantees, for example stated in 6.6 and 10.4, do not apply when accessing native memory segments as these segments are backed by off-heap regions of memory.*” but considering which chapters have been linked, I have the feeling that the author of this sentence uses the term “memory model” wrongly, as these chapters have nothing to do with the JMM.

Comment: Access control? Array access? How is that relevant for the memory model? Does that sentence mean I need to add specific synchronization mechanism to off-heap memory, as "Usual memory model guarantees" do not apply? What are those alternatives?

Comment: It irritates me as well. That’s why I said, I have the feeling, the author of the sentence uses the term “memory model” wrongly. I think, we have to request clarification from the JDK developers.